# Dynamically Created Subviews within Subclassed UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, cgrect

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class and would like to display images and strings linearly. For example:

> Row 1: [Image1] string1 [Image2] string2 [Image3]
>
> Row 2: [Image4] string3 [Image5]

The images have varying widths but I would like equal spacing. How would I do this? I have tried manipulating subviews and `CGRectMake` to no avail.

Additionally, I am using an `NSDictionary` to hold the content and the number of images/string is not constant for each cell.

My `CustomCell` class:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"


@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize primaryLabel,secondaryLabel,image1;


-  (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        // Initialization code
        primaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        primaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        primaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
        secondaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        secondaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        secondaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

        [self.contentView addSubview:primaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:secondaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:image1];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect frame;
    frame= CGRectMake(0 ,5, 200, 25);
    primaryLabel.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(0 ,30, 200, 25);
    secondaryLabel.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(0, 60, 23, 20);
    image1.frame = frame;
```

...

My `RootViewController`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSDictionary *dictionary = nil;


//Search
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        dictionary = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


//Original
    cell.primaryLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];    


    for (NSArray *keystroke in [dictionary objectForKey:@"Strokes"]) {


           for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {


               if ([(NSString *)keystroke isEqualToString:@"string1"] || [(NSString *)keystroke isEqualToString:@"string2"]) {
                 cell.secondaryLabel.text = (NSString *)keystroke; 
                 }

               else { 
            NSString *imageFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", keystroke];
            NSLog(@"%@", imageFilePath);
            UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFilePath];

                cell.image1.image = myimage;

        }
        }
    }
    return cell;


}
```

...

Obviously there are a lot of holes here. Primarily, as I loop through my dictionary, I need to move my `CustomCell` subview right so I can place the images/text next to the previous subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. In your `UITableViewCell` subclass, you will need to override `layoutSubviews`, define `CGRects` for each `UIImageView` or `UILabel` manually, and set them as the respective view's frame.

Check out [CGRectGetMaxX](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectGetMaxX). It will be very useful in this context.

Comment: I've added some code, because I'm still lost. Thanks for the reply!